# How to change the panel position to mouse position in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want a panel to be shown at the position the mouse on the screen.

The Firefox SDK documentation is not very detailed and I face some problems understanding how I can change the panel position.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you cannot. If I look at the source code, the Add-on SDK always shows the panels in the middle of the browser window. There is merely an undocumented option to anchor the panel at a node in some web page but this is clearly undocumented for a reason (SDK extensions usually cannot get hold of such nodes). Even if that option were usable, it wouldn't solve your problem. I guess that the "easiest" solution would be taking `packages/addon-kit/lib/panel.js` and using a modified version in your extension where the method `show()` can take screen coordinates (the parameters `x` and `y` in the `openPopup()` call at the bottom of this method are screen coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a button in the Nav Bar and then show a panel by it instead of using a Widget to show a button as that is tied to the Addon Toolbar.

To put a button in the Nav-Bar I used the code here:

http://kendsnyder.com/posts/firefox-extensions-add-button-to-nav-bar

In his code you will notice that there is a bit that looks like this:

```
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // do stuff, for example with tabs or pageMod
}, false)
```

As Wladimir mentioned you must anchor the panel to an element so in the click event I added the following:

```
panel.show(utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document.getElementById("myButton"));
```

I declared utils as such:

```
var utils = require("sdk/window/utils");
```

You can actually anchor your [Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) to any element in the browser. For example, you can anchor it to the nav bar:

```
 panel.show(utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document.getElementById("nav-bar"));
```

or anchor to the status bar like so:

```
panel.show(utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document.getElementById("statusbar-display"));
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers!